# R add1 function, scope argument to reference all variables

Tags: r

When using the add1 function to consider new variables, I would like to reference all variables (either in some dataframe or global environment), but I can not figure out how to use the scope argument to do this.

I am aware I can use it like this

```
X = data.frame(replicate(4,rnorm(20))) ; y = rnorm(20)
lm1 = lm(y ~ 1)
out = add1(lm1, scope= ~X$X1 + X$X2 + X$X3)
```

but I want to avoid manually writing in every variable.

As I have seen in other questions, I know the . symbol will not work but I am not sure why. It stands for what is already there, so if I do

```
x1 = rnorm(20) ; x2 = rnorm(20) ; x3 = rnorm(20) ; x4 = rnorm(20) ; y = rnorm(20)
out = add1(lm1, scope= ~ . )
```

it does not use what is already in the global environment.

I know the documentation says that scope must be "a formula giving the terms to be considered", but that is usually where . can be used to reference all variables.

Thanks in advance.

Also note I have read Chp 7 of MASS, and these related threads

[scope from add1()-command in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923577/scope-from-add1-command-in-r)

http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/02b/3588.html

Comment: Afer some interval (the length of which I do not know) you will be able to post it as an answer. I encourage you to do so. I agree it is better than what I offered.

Comment: Ok, I will try later. I also found a 2nd method which you may find of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an even simpler answer, which I found after browsing this question

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/glm-formula-vs-character-td2543061.html

```
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = rnorm(100)
x3 = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)


BaseReg = lm(y ~ 1)
newdf = data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

out = add1(BaseReg, names(newdf))
```

It is baffling that such a simple way to get this was not stated in the documentation for add1.

Answer (score 0):

As the help page for add1 says the formula `~.` means "what's already there". It is not any simpler to use `as.formula` for small numbers of names but this approach can be using in a function or script. (Generally one would expect to put the X's and Y in the same dataframe.)

```
as.formula(paste("~", paste(names(YX)[-c(1,5)],collapse="+")))
#~X1 + X2 + X3

YX <- cbind(y,X)
form <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(names(YX)[-c(1,5)],collapse="+")))
add1(lm1, form)
```

You appear to have stumbled across a more efficient strategy. If using a data object with column names:  "y"  "X1" "X2" "X3"

```
"X4:

> formula(YX)
y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4
> formula(YX)[-2]
~X1 + X2 + X3 + X4
> as.list(formula(YX))
[[1]]
`~`

[[2]]
y

[[3]]
X1 + X2 + X3 + X4

> names(YX)
[1] "y"  "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4"
```

You can see that a formula object has as its first element the formula-defining tilde which is really an R function. The second element is the LHS expression and the third elemtn is the RHS expression.

Comment: This method works, although it is still automating a way to write out all of the individual variable names, and is still a bit more manual than I would like. After looking through the as.formula doc I have stumbled upon what I think is a more elegant solution in line with what I was hoping for, so I have put that as another answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I found that works:

```
X = data.frame(replicate(4,rnorm(20))) 
lm1 = lm(X1 ~ 1 ,data=X)
add1(lm1, scope=formula(X)[-2])
```

Granted, I have no idea why this is the case

```
formula(X)[-2]
# ~X2 + X3 + X4
```

I just found it by accident. Other things like formula(X)[-1] and formula(X)[-3] also return other things which are equally bizarre to me.