# Stepwise forward regression - adding one term

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to know if there is an argument in the **step()** function that would allow me to update a model with a single term as part of a forward regression. Simply put, I want to be able to delete a term of my fitted **lm()** model, exclude it from the data I use to perform the stepwise regression and see which variable pops out of the data to replace it in the forward regression if I perform another one just to replace the deleted variable. Here is what it would look like:

```
test<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df)
testbis<-lm(y~x1+x3, data=df)

testfinal<-step(testbis, direction="forward", scope=?, data=df[,-c("x2")])
```

I assume it's the scope expression I can't pinpoint accurately. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have a look at `?update`

Comment: @etienne but the update function does not allow for a stepwise selection of the added variable, does it?

Comment: I don't think it does, although it could be a part of the `step` function to replace `testbis` and avoid the `data=df[...]`. You could look at `add1` which might be a better solution than `step`

Comment: Stepwise regression is seen very critically by statisticians. There are better methods.

Comment: @etienne Just found out about it, took me a while to get the right scope argument but it works! Thanks.

Comment: [List of problems with stepwise regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/11849) and [some alternatives](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13686/11849).

Comment: Please do not add the "solution" to the question. Post an answer instead. (You are encouraged to answer your own question.)

Comment: Done. And thanks for the useful tips. I can't help but notice that MARS models are not listed in the viable alternatives. Any particular reason?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96180/discussion-between-user2092517-and-roland).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the use of the **add1()** function; I simply delete the variable I don't want and then do an add1 test on my df. This would give something like this:

```
test1<-add1(testbis, scope=formula(df[,-c("y")])[-2])
```

You have to remove the response variable otherwise you get an error message, and the '[-2]' gives the right formula for the scope (see post here: [R add1 function, scope argument to reference all variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049488/r-add1-function-scope-argument-to-reference-all-variables))